# How to create Entity Class for multiple table joins

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am developing a spring boot application, i need a proper design help for one of my entity relation.

These are my tables

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user;
CREATE TABLE user
(
 User_ID   INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 Email     VARCHAR(1024),
 Phone     BIGINT,
 Password  VARCHAR(128),
 User_Type ENUM ('TEACHER', 'PARENT'),
 Status    ENUM ('ACTIVE', 'DEACTIVE', 'SUSPENDED')
 );

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS teacher;
CREATE TABLE teacher
(
   Teacher_ID      INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   Name            VARCHAR(1024),
   Email           VARCHAR(1024),
   Phone           BIGINT,
   Gender          ENUM (0, 1),
   Date_Of_Joining INT,
   Designation     VARCHAR(1024),
   Is_Active       INT
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS parent;
CREATE TABLE parent
(
  Parent_ID  INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  Name       VARCHAR(1024),
  Email      VARCHAR(1024),
  Phone      BIGINT,
  Occupation VARCHAR(1024),
  Address    VARCHAR(4048)
);


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS student;
CREATE TABLE student
(
  Student_ID    INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  Student_Name  VARCHAR(1024),
  Class         VARCHAR(16),
  Section       VARCHAR(16),
  Academic_Year VARCHAR(64),
  DOB           DATE,
  Gender        ENUM (0, 1),
  Parent_ID     INT
);
```

Can anyone please help me creating entity classes for the same. Based on the type of user in user table i need to join with either teacher or parent table. For example if User_Type is TEACHER then i will join with teacher table else i will join user with parent table. Join condition would be email.

Student table has one to one relationship with parent table.

Answer (score 0):

You can create domain models like this

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)
public User{

    //properties

}

@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
public  Teacher extends User{

    //properties

}


@Entity
public Parent extends User{

   //properties
}

@Entity
public Students {


    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign",parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "stock"))
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "Parent_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public Parent parent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following classes:

User:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "User_ID")
private Integer userID;

@Column(name = "name", length = 1024)
private String name;

@Column(name = "email", length = 1024)
private String email;

@Column(name = "Phone")
private Long phone;

@Column(name = "Password", length = 128)
private String password;

@Column(name = "User_Type", columnDefinition = "enum ('TEACHER', 'PARENT')")
private String userType;

@Column(name = "Status", columnDefinition = "enum ('ACTIVE', 'DEACTIVE', 'SUSPENDED')")
private String status;
}
```

Teacher:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teacher")
public class Teacher extends User{
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "teacher_ID")
private Integer teacherID;

@Column(name = "name", length = 1024)
private String name;

@Column(name = "email", length = 1024)
private String email;

@Column(name = "Phone")
private Long phone;

@Column(name = "Gender", columnDefinition = "BOOLEAN")
private Boolean gender;

@Column(name = "Date_Of_Joining")
private Integer dateOfJoining;

@Column(name = "Designation", length = 1024)
private String designation;

@Column(name = "Is_Active")
private Integer isActive;
}
```

Parent:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent extends User{
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "Parent_ID")
private Integer parentID;

@Column(name = "name", length = 1024)
private String name;

@Column(name = "email", length = 1024)
private String email;

@Column(name = "Phone")
private Long phone;

@Column(name = "Occupation", length = 1024)
private String occupation;

@Column(name = "Address",length=4048)
private String address;
}
```

Student:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "Student_ID")
private Integer studentID;

@Column(name = "student_name", length = 1024)
private String studentName;

@Column(name = "study_class", length = 16)
private String studyClass;

@Column(name = "section", length = 16)
private String section;

@Column(name = "academic_year",length = 64)
private String academicYear;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "dob", length = 4048)
private Date dob;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "parent")
public Parent parent;
}
```

Try them out and see if that helps.

Comment: But on what basis JOIN condition will be generated. For example Teacher is joined to User Table with join condition User_Type. Its only while fetching time. Can you provide me the Query get All teachers joined with user? that would e grateful.